# "even" position in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, adverb-position

I found an example: *I haven’t even started making dinner.* What about *I even haven't started making dinner*? Would it be also correct?

Comment: Adverbs like _even_ and _only_ are normally placed right after the first auxiliary verb, if there is one. So _I haven't even started_ is fine, but *_I even haven't started_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: ***Even** I haven't started dinner* works, but it means something different -- a comparison with other people making dinner instead of a comparison with other activities.

Comment: [If you please, see my answer for a similar question.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/456535/305707)

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Adverbs like *even* and *only* are normally placed right after the first auxiliary verb, if there is one. So *I haven't even started* is fine, but **I even haven't started* is ungrammatical.