# "may even have" or "may have even"?

Tags: word-order, adverb-position

Is either of these 'more correct'?

1. She may **even** have pre-empted us.
2. She may have **even** pre-empted us.

Is it purely a case of which sounds better in any case, or are there specific rules?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/346007/2085).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a matter of adverb placement. *Even* is used here as an adverb and *have* is an auxiliary verb. The *Chicago Manual of Style* holds as follows:

> "When an adverb qualifies a verb phrase, the normal place for the adverb is between the auxiliary verb and the principal verb {the administration **has consistently repudiated** this view} {the reports **will soon generate** controversy} {public opinion **is sharply divided**}. Some adverbs may follow the principal verb {you must go **quietly**} {are you asking **rhetorically**?}. There has never been a rule against placing an adverbial modifier between the auxiliary verb and the principal verb in a verb phrase. In fact, it’s typically preferable to put the adverb there {the heckler was **abruptly** expelled} {the bus had been **seriously** damaged in the crash}."

Based on this, I would say that the former sentence is more aligned with what the CMS recommends. This doesn't mean, however, that the latter sentence is *incorrect*.

This is also from the CMS; you might find this useful:

> "The combination of an auxiliary verb with a principal verb is a verb phrase, such as *could happen*, *must go*, or *will be leaving*. **When a verb phrase is modified by an adverb, the modifier typically goes directly after the first auxiliary verb,** as in *could certainly happen*, *must always go*, and *will soon be leaving*. The idea that verb phrases should not be “split” in this way is quite mistaken..."

Comment: But the verb phrase may contain *both* a modal and an aspect auxiliary (like the OP example).  In that case placement of the adverb may carry some nuance.

Comment: Why? They're still auxiliary verbs.

Comment: The adverb *even* is still qualifying the verb phrase "may have preempted."

Comment: Thank you for correcting me.  If there is no difference then that is evidence that modals and aspects are stored together in the same memory element.  (The CMS would recommend the first version "... may even have ...")

Comment: I'm only going by what the CMS says.

Comment: [Often] I [often] will [often] have [often] been [often] wrong [often].