# Position of manner adverbs within verb phrases

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, adverb-position

I have found the following sentence in a book:

> A firm's sensory marketing approach should be deliberately and
>   strategically based on the five human senses.

I have a feeling that the adverbial phrase *deliberately and strategically* should be put in the verb phrase **should be based** as ***should deliberately and strategically be based***. However, I am not sure whether this is just a matter of style or if in fact there is some slight difference in meaning between these two options.

Answer (score 1):

This is my [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/456535/305707) to a similar question. Perhaps it’ll be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Because "deliberately and strategically" is clearly marked as adverbial (by '-ly'), it can go anywhere in the clause (except within a noun phrase or prepositional phrase) and be grammatical (although putting it inside a negation will change the meaning).  As a matter of style, placement after the first verbal (in this case 'should') is well accepted.